# Display data in gridview same as in database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am creating a website for online exam in which first questions are inserted into database. 
That question may be like

```
`<Script type=JavaScript/text> 
Function display()
{
 document.write("a");
} 
</script>`
```

is save in database but when i tried display list of all question in gridview that particular question create problem, means it not showing in grid.

Have any idea ?.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure GridView column that displays this data has its `HtmlEncode` property set to `True`. This way script tags will be encoded and actually displayed on the page. E.g.

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Question"
            headertext="Question"
            htmlencode="true" />
```

`True` is a default value. But perhaps your code/markup changes it for some reason or another.

Comment: thanks Galanter, i have used that but in this case all text is coming in single line means that is not coming in same format in different lines